# Java reflections: Set field value best practice

Tags: java, reflection

Assuming that there is no special logic in a field set method, What would be the best practice to set field's value using reflections? would it be

```
  field.set(obj, value);
```

or

```
  method = obj.getClass().getMethod("setSomething", parameter.class);
  method.invoke(obj, argument);
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, it depends. There are [many good reasons](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1568091/why-use-getters-and-setters-accessors) to use setter methods and if they are available, you should also use them via reflection. But you must be sure that the setter method exists otherwise an exception will occur. And if you want to prevent any (explicit unwanted) side effect you should also avoid using a setter method.